# Inclusion of Lebesgue measurable set by open and closed sets for infinte measure

Tags: real-analysis

If $A \in \mathcal M (\lambda^n)$ is Lebesgue measurable and $\epsilon > 0$, there exist a closed set $ F \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ and an open set $G \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ with $F \subseteq A \subseteq G,~ \lambda^n(G \backslash A) < \epsilon,~ \lambda^n(A \backslash F) <\epsilon$.

Can somebody tell me why this holds even if $\lambda^n (A) = \infty$?

Comment: Because $\lambda$ is $\sigma$-finite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$\bigcup_n X_n = \mathbb{R}^n$$
be a decomposition of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (say by cubes) so that $X_n$'s are pairwise disjoint and the measures are finite.

There exsits such closed $F_n\subseteq A\cap X_n$ that $\lambda^n(\left(A\cap X_n \right)\backslash F_n)<\epsilon/2^n$, whose union
$$F = \bigcup_n F_n$$
is also closed and satisfies $\lambda^n(A\backslash F)<\sum_n\epsilon/2^n =\epsilon$,.

As an open $G$ you can simply take $\mathbb{R}^n$, since it is open.